# How to print view hierarchy to console while testing in detox

Tags: reactjs, react-native, detox

I am running the tests with detox test -c android, I would like to print the view hierarchy to console while testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the `--loglevel trace` flag.

```
detox test --loglevel trace -c android
```

detox test log level docs: https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/api/detox-cli/#test